# How to add line breaks within tooltip in angular material design

Tags: angularjs, tooltip, angular-material

How to add line break in tooltip 
I have implemented the Tooltip but i am not able to add multi line or line breaks in tooltip.Below is my code

http://codepen.io/apps4any/pen/RWQLyr

Html

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" class="tooltipdemoBasicUsage" ng-app="MyApp">
  <md-content layout-padding="">
    <md-button class="md-fab md-fab-top-right right" aria-label="Photos">
      <md-icon md-svg-src="img/icons/ic_photo_24px.svg" style="width: 24px; height: 24px;"></md-icon>
      <md-tooltip>
        List1<br>
        List2<br>
        List3<br>
        List4
      </md-tooltip>
    </md-button>
    <div style="margin-top: 150px;">
    </div>
  </md-content>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.tooltipdemoBasicUsage md-toolbar .md-toolbar-tools .md-button, .tooltipdemoBasicUsage md-toolbar .md-toolbar-tools .md-button:hover {
  box-shadow: none;
  border: none;
  transform: none;
  -webkit-transform: none; }
.tooltipdemoBasicUsage .left {
  top: 70px !important;
  left: 56px !important; }
.tooltipdemoBasicUsage .right {
  top: 70px !important;
  right: 56px !important; }
```

JS

```
angular.module('MyApp')
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.demo = {};
});
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Adding this CSS seems to work in your case (with the `<br>`s):

```
md-tooltip .md-content {
    height: auto;
}
```

I'm not sure why Angular-Material hard-coded the height to 22px. You'll need to check whether this change breaks other tooltips.

Or you can apply it specifically to this use case only by giving it a class, e.g. `tt-multiline`, so you can target it in CSS:

```
md-tooltip.tt-multiline .md-content {
    height: auto;
}
```

---

Edit: Starting from Angular-Material 1.1, some class names have changed to start with a underscore.

In this case use

```
md-tooltip ._md-content {
    height: auto;
}
```

and for specific class

```
md-tooltip.tt-multiline ._md-content {
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: As far as I can see, when having multi lines, the positioning is not working very well if it is at the end of the page. I am using a button with a tooltip which is then on top of the button.

Comment: @Icycool: I have a dynamic element to be rendered as a tooltip, so don't have an option to add <br/> there. Any idea on how to show the tooltip so the text renders on the next line instead of getting clipped?

Comment: @user1242321 You can check css `white-space:pre` or `white-space:pre-wrap`

Comment: It's worth noting that angular material class names prefixed with an underscore are temporary styles that will change in future versions.

Comment: user1242321 see my answer @ bottom

Answer (score 11):

Since **angular-material version >1.1.2** you can simply override `.md-tooltip` class: 
([JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/The_Bear/n36s07vL/6/))

```
.md-tooltip {
    height: auto;
}
```

---

And if you want to style a particular tooltip, add a custom class to `md-tooltip` element:

([jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/The_Bear/bxqh08oq/4/))

HTML

```
<md-tooltip class="tooltip-multiline">
    I'm a multiline <br/> tooltip
</md-tooltip>
```

CSS

```
.tooltip-multiline {
  height: auto;
}
```

*both cases tested in angular-material 1.1.2, 1.1.3 and 1.1.4 versions*

Answer (score 7):

Set the `max-with`'s below to what ever you need. Now it will do automatic line breaks or put a `<br/>`
into it.

```
md-tooltip .md-content {
    height: auto !important;
    max-width: 200px !important;
    font-size: 13px !important;
}

md-tooltip {
    height: auto !important;
    max-width: 200px !important;
    font-size: 13px !important;
    overflow: visible !important;
    white-space: normal !important;
}

md-tooltip ._md-content {
    height: auto !important;
    max-width: 200px !important;
    font-size: 13px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can view the styling for md-tooltip (v0.11.4) here: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/0.11.4/angular-material.css

My own overwrites to the material design styling to allow nice looking multi-line tooltips:

```
md-tooltip {
  font-family: Roboto, 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  .md-background {
    border-radius: inherit;
  }
  .md-content {
    height: auto;
    width: 400px;
    max-width: 400px;
    padding: 8px;
    white-space: initial;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  md-tooltip .md-content {
    font-size: 14px;
    height: auto;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 8px;
    max-width: 300px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Or you can use `white-space: pre-line;` in the custom class of your md tooltip. :)

Answer (score 1):

After a while searching for a solution **FROM A VARIABLE CONTENT**:

### .ts

```
public matTooltipContent: string = 'Line 1 comment\nLine 2 comment\nLine 3 comment'
```

### .html

```
  <button mat-icon-button aria-hidden="false" class="material-icons-outlined"
      [matTooltip]="matTooltipContent"
      matTooltipClass="allow-cr"
      (click)="onInfoButtonClicked($event)">
    <mat-icon >help_outlined</mat-icon>
  </button>
```

### .css

```
.allow-cr {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

[See stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-multiline-tooltips-sjg9ke)

Answer (score 0):

I am using `angular_material 1.1.8`, for me single answer didn't work, a combination did.

html

```
<md-tooltip class="tooltip-multiline">Years ago, when I was backpacking...</md-tooltip>
```

css

```
.tooltip-multiline {
    height: auto;
    white-space: pre-line; 
    max-width:300px;
    line-height: 14px; /*optional*/
    font-weight:200;/*optional*/
    letter-spacing: 0.5px; /*optional*/
    font-size:11px;/*optional*/     
}
```

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

angular material tool tip is warping all content in  div so this its working

```
<md-tooltip class="tooltip-multiline" md-direction="left">
          This is tooltip
</md-tooltip>

.tooltip-multiline div{
  height: auto;
}
```