# Styling md-tooltip (Angular Material 1.1.3)

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

I have a mat-tooltip that I was styling through a CSS like this:

```
mat-tooltip .mat-content {
    // custom values, styling is not applied
}
```

However since 1.1.2 release of angular material this styling is not being applied to my tooltips. Has anybody encountered a similar issue?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to **style all your tooltips**, just override `.md-tooltip` class: 
([JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/The_Bear/8nvo8n53/13/))

```
.md-tooltip {
    height: 35px !important;
    background-color: red !important;
    color: white !important;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

---

If you want **particularly style some tooltips**, use a custom class over `md-tooltip` element:

([jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/The_Bear/dep2exfg/1/))

HTML

```
<md-tooltip class="custom-tooltip">
    I'm a custom tooltip
</md-tooltip>
```

CSS

```
.custom-tooltip {
  top: 25px !important;
  height: 35px !important;
  background-color: red !important;
  color: white !important;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: I read in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33293599/how-to-add-line-breaks-within-tooltip-in-angular-material-design) that since Angular Material 1.1.1 the class name temporally starts with an underscore...              `md-tooltip ._md-content { height: auto; }`.
Maybe could be that too.

Comment: Oooohh :)  In any case your answered worked, thank you The.Bear!

Comment: @The.Bear Is it possible to apply the md-tooltip css to only one tooltip in my page?

Comment: You have to add your custom class into a md-tooltip element. For instance: `<md-tooltip class="custom-tooltip"></md-tooltip>`. [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/The_Bear/dep2exfg/1/)