# I want to make the mat-icon to have multi line tooltip. I tried in the following way with out having \n displayed in tooltip

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, material-design, angular6

I tried to have a multiline tooltip with below example. you can see \n is displaying in the tooltip. I want to have a break as we do with html kind of tooltip
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1e3np3-hbxpo2?file=app%2Ftooltip-auto-hide-example.css

Comment: You can't put html in tooltips. This is contrary to the [material design spec](https://material.io/design/components/tooltips.html#implementation). Checkout [this feature request](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/5440) for more information

Comment: Possible Duplicate of 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47058483/angular-2-material-mattooltip-multiline

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33293599/how-to-add-line-breaks-within-tooltip-in-angular-material-design

Comment: this is not latest material design @s

Comment: i want it with angular 2 or above.  its not working for that

Comment: Please see the below link of how i want to render the tooltip
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1e3np3-hbxpo2?file=app%2Ftooltip-auto-hide-example.css

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is working but you need to increase the width of the tooltip if you want a clearer effect - [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1e3np3-5tf2sr)

```
::ng-deep .material-tooltip {
  white-space: pre-line;
  max-width: 500px !important;
}
```

[image]